# Python dict ambiguity

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I want to use the Python keyword dict to return a dictionary with every word as true of a given sentence.
The code snippet is:

```
return dict((word, True) for word in words)
```

Now, the ambiguity occurs when both the codes return same dictionaries:

1.

```
return dict((word, True) for word in words)
```

2.

```
return dict([(word, True) for word in words])
```

Why doesn't the second snippet return a dict with list of words inside?

Comment: because `[ example for example in examples ]` is list comprehension, some docs http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: because `[(word, True) for word in words]` is a list and for a dictionary you need Key, Value pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of those snippets are essentially identical to:

```
return dict.fromkeys(words, True)
```

Which is a mapping where the keys are the items in `words` and the values are True.

The `dict` class also takes an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs, which is what you are creating in both of those snippets.

In the first, it is a generator expression, so not all the items are created at once, but they are created as it is iterated over.

The second is a list compression, so a list is created to begin with and all the items are created and put into a list.

In either case, `dict` sees an iterable.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `dict.fromkeys`. You could also mention that it runs much faster than the OP's versions, especially if `words` is large, since it loops at C speed.

Comment: So, in case if words is a really long string, comprising around 1000000+ independent words, the first way of making the dict, i.e. using a generator expression would take comparatively more time to execute?